# d is a divisor function then $\sum_{n \leq x} d(n)= \sum_{d \leq x} \lfloor \frac{x}{d}\rfloor$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I know that $\lfloor \frac{x}{d} \rfloor$ is the number of multiples of d in [1,x].
To prove the equality I tried to argue that on the RHS the summing is over d and so we are counting the number of multiples of d in [1,x] and we are taking d from 1 to $\lfloor x \rfloor$. But, I am unable to justify that the sum should equal to LHS.

Any help is highly appreciated. If possible please help me to get a proof without calculations.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how to interchange the sums.

$\displaystyle \sum_{n \le x} d(n) = \sum_{n \le x} \sum_{d \mid n} 1 = \sum_{d \le x} \sum_{d \mid n \atop n \le x} 1 = \sum_{d \le x} \lfloor x/d \rfloor$

Comment: The last equality is not clear to me. Can you please guide me with this?

Comment: I forgot the condition $n \le x$ and edited the answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes it is clear now. Thanks!